# Best way to create a data up-loader service for my application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, file-upload, ssis

I have an application that's built on .Net Core. There's a lot of Data and a lot of linkages between the tables. 
I would like to create a service where the client can download a template(Excel File) and upload it back with data filled. And I need to read the data and apply the necessary logic to the Data and dump it in the Database. 
I know I can use the IFormFile where I can just read the file into a DataTable and create a Model and somehow Map it. 
I was wondering if there's a better way I can do this.

Just a thought - Can I somehow use SSIS?
Please suggest the best way I can do this. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There's a lot packed into this question.  Would be useful if you could elaborate on where you're getting stuck - or break the question down into several questions.  In terms of the saving it to a database - how are you doing your database interactions? You might want to consider using an ORM like Entity Framework.  Also is there a specific need to use Excel files over CSV?

Comment: There is no better way to do this, but only a way where you are pratical. I think that use SSIS is a good solution, but depends on how are you skilfull about SSIS.